Adopting flexible character forms in Chinese SE's search functionality
It has recently come to my attention that part of the reason of the difficulty in moderating content by searching for existing answers and questions is due to character forms. This means that an exact duplicate of another question or answer may not even show up in a search! Here is a screenshot of a recently active question:

 

The Chinese text in the question is in Simplified Chinese (在什么情况下), and searching for it turns up.

 

Searching the exact same content in Traditional Chinese (在什麼情況下) doesn't turn up any search results. This makes searching for existing questions and answers extremely difficult.

 

Most importantly, we have users which type in a mixture of both, which means that their content isn't searchable at all by the average user, because most Chinese users type in either Simplified or Traditional Chinese, not a mixture.

 


I've noticed Google search in Chinese is flexible in character searching. Can we implement this for Chinese SE's search functionality?

 


If I'm not mistaken, Stack Exchange is using Elasticsearch. This answer on SO might be the solution for their side.

@AndrewT. thanks - that's a good start for us if we escalate this onto the main meta site.

i guess you’re requesting “google custom search”
https://developers.google.com/custom-search
or, try the syntax “search in specified site only”:
[type in the search field]

"在什麼情況下" site:https://chinese.stackexchange.com

have fun :)
